# Import excel file using angular and convert that excel sheet data in array using REST API in .net core

Tags: javascript, .net

The frontend is in Angular.
The backend is in .net Core.

1. trying to develop an import excel sheet functionality so in the frontend, I am using angular where I want to import the file and I need to convert that excel data into array format or  in JSON
2. for convert excel into an array I want one rest API in .net core ( i don't want to use XSLX PAckage from angular)

this method I developed, here I am  passing FILE as bsae64 in request body to these API

```
   public async Task<dynamic> converexceltotAray()
    {
        using (StreamReader steamread = new StreamReader(Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string s = await steamread.ReadToEndAsync();
            byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(newBytes)) {
                byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
                var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
            var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {
                    //ReadHeaderRow = (rowReader) => {
                    // for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    // {
                    // rowReader.Read();
                    // }
                    //},
                    UseHeaderRow = true,
                }
            });
            DataTable table = result.Tables[1];
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
            //rtxtOutPut.Text = json;
            //stream.Close();
            return json;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @GabrielLlorico i added in description